# How do print the following pattern in C/C++?

Tags: c++

(For n=4)

```
1
2*3
4*5*6
7*8*9*10
7*8*9*10
4*5*6
2*3
1
```

Printing the above half triangle is quite easy but I couldn't figure out how to print the lower triangle.

This is how I printed the above half triangle.

```
int num = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {   
        cout << num;
        if (i != j)
        {  
             cout << "*";
        } 
          num++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to answer your not-question.

Comment: Write down the steps you took to complete the first part of the triangle. Then reverse the steps, and do that. Done.

Comment: @remyabel That seems logical, but actually is not true since the lines must be printed from left to right.  So after printing 7,8,9,10 you can't reverse and print 10,9,8,7.

Comment: @user3386109 Really? You don't  have to change what you print, just what order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach :

```
int cur=1,num=1;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<cur;j++)
    {
        if(j!=0)
          printf("*");
        printf("%d",num++);
    }
    printf("\n");
    cur++;
}
cur=4,num=10;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    int temp=num-cur+1;
    for(int j=0;j<cur;j++)
    {
        if(j!=0)
          printf("*");
        printf("%d",temp++);
    }
    printf("\n");
    num-=cur;
    cur--;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is that you wouldn't know from which number to start when you are writing each line of the lower triangle, just create an array of `n` strings and instead of printing each line, save each of them while you are making the upper triangle. Then, print them first from line 1 to line n, and then from n to 1.

Otherwise you could calculate the starting number of each line. Line 5 (counting from 1, to make it consistent with n; in other words, the first one of the lower triangle, that contains 7, 8, 9, 10) is identical to line 4, and line n=4 starts at the number that comes after the sum of all numbers from 1 to `n-1`. The sum of numbers from 1 to `n-1` is simply `(n-1)*n/2`. So you can know that with n=4 you have to calculate the sum of numbers from 1 to 3, which is 3*4/2=6, and at line 4 you start from 6+1=7. And being line 4 you have to print 4 numbers.

Comment: I also thought about storing it in a string and the printing that as required but couldn't implement it due to very less knowledge of strings. But your second approach is very nice. Will try to implement it.